# Avoid other apps using the same framework to access the keychain data in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, keychain

I have a framework which stores data in Keychain.
Is there a way what can I do to prevent access to that data from other apps in a device which has more apps using the same framework? And can they access it?
I googled a lot but could not find a good answer to this question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the default situation. Each app has its own access group by default, and things put into Keychain are limited to that access group. The framework isn't relevant, only the app ID (and by extension the access group or groups).

For more on access groups, see [Sharing Access to Keychain Items Among a Collection of Apps](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps) for how apps (from the same development team) *can* share Keychain items. But the default is that they don't.

Comment: so it's safe for the app to keep the data there and if you did not turn ON sharing then other apps using the same framework cannot access that data, right?

Comment: Correct. Even if you did turn on sharing, apps from another team will not be able to access the items, and even apps from your team would only be able to access the items if the access group is configured correctly. There is no way to share Keychain items "globally." The framework being used doesn't matter. Every Keychain wrapper eventually has to make calls to Apple's Security.framework, and that's where the permissions are controlled.